# SQL count(*) only returns one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner in mysql. The following codes look stupid but it is why my codes cannot work. I thought it would give me *n* rows. However, it only gave me one row. Suppose there are *n* rows in the table `seat`, and there are two fields including *id*, *student*.

I understand count(*) will return one number. I thought that, for each row, sql will check whether id equals total number of rows. But it didn't.

```
select id = count(*) as id, student 
from seat
```

The following codes did what I wanted. Could anyone explain what makes them give different results?

```
select id = count2 as id, student 
from seat, (select count(*) as count2 from seat) seat2
```

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: for the reason why it gave you one row only, pls check here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count

Comment: You should reread the count with group by section in the tutorial

Comment: @user1506104 For each row, I want to check whether the _id_ equals to the number of rows, if it is, I will perform some operation.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm not asking how to use `count` in general. I'm asking why mysql will not check whether id = count(*) for each row.

Comment: @W.Yang Are you sure, it is really work?

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
set @num := (select count(*) from seat);

select
      id
    , student
    , case when id = @num then 'special' else 'normal' end as x
from seat
```

Another way:

```
select
      id
    , student
    , case when id = x.y then 'special' else 'normal' end as x
from seat
cross join (select count(*) as y from seat) as x
;
```

**NB**: In both examples you need the subquery to return just one value in one row.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
+----+----------+
| id | lastname |
+----+----------+
|  1 | aaa      |
|  2 | bbb      |
|  3 | ccc      |
+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your first query is an instruction to mysql to count across the entire set

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id = count(*) as id, lastname
    -> from users;
+------+----------+
| id   | lastname |
+------+----------+
|    0 | aaa      |
+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Clearly this does not return the last id or the correct count. The correct count would be returned by this

```
select  id, lastname , count(*)
from users;
+------+----------+----------+
| id   | lastname | count(*) |
+------+----------+----------+
|    1 | aaa      |        3 |
+------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the id and lastname are indeterminate.

Your second query returns a cartesian product

```
select id = count2, lastname, count2
    -> from users, (select count(*) as count2 from users) seat2
    -> ;
+-------------+----------+--------+
| id = count2 | lastname | count2 |
+-------------+----------+--------+
|           0 | aaa      |      3 |
|           0 | bbb      |      3 |
|           1 | ccc      |      3 |
+-------------+----------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which again does not identify the id which matches the count..

Assuming the id is a number and increments in some fashion a way which does find the last id is

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,lastname
    -> from users
    -> where  id = (select count(*) from users);
+----+----------+
| id | lastname |
+----+----------+
|  3 | ccc      |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But this is dangerous - if id is auto_increment then the number of rows may not match the id because of the way auto_increment is treated (it can be overridden, insert update on duplicate key etc.)
A safer way is to

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,lastname
    -> from users
    -> where  id = (select max(id) from users);
+----+----------+
| id | lastname |
+----+----------+
|  3 | ccc      |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this :

```
select id = (select count(*) from seat) as id, student 
from seat
```

Basically your previous request with this statement in the FROM clause `(select count(*) as count2 from seat)` gives you only row so it can't compare to all of your rows because you put it in your FROM clause two tables seat and seat2 without the same number of rows.

I think you don't need to use two tables.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it [count(*)] would give me n rows. However, it only gave me one row.

Nope.  You are using `COUNT(*)` with no `GROUP BY`.  That makes your query an aggregation query.  An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` *always* returns one row -- even when there are no rows in the table.

Your query would be invalid in almost any other database (and in the default configuration of future versions of MySQL) because you have an aggregation query and the column `id` is not in the `GROUP BY` nor an argument to an aggregation function.

In MySQL, probably the simplest way to do what you intend uses a subquery:

```
select id = (select count(*) from seat) as id, student 
from seat
```

I have no idea why you would want to call the boolean result `id`, but that is what your original query expresses.

Conclusion:  You need to practice aggregation queries and look up what `GROUP BY` does.